# How to display "English" link on Arabic website and "Arabic" link on English website

Tags: sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-enterprise, master-page, page-layout, multilingual

I want to display link "Arabic" on my English site so user can click on it to view "Arabic" version. I want to do similar thing on my Arabic site where it will display link "English".

How do I do that?

The place where I will display these words is defined in my Master Page. Or I can do it in Page Layout if not possible in Master Page but need some guidance on it.

Answer (score 1):

SharePoint 2010 offers 2 ways of multilanguage support:

- MUI - which is basically loading of resources for standard menus
  according to language currently selected
- Variations - which actually consists in using "labels" for languages (more details http://hermansberghem.blogspot.ch/2009/10/best-practices-to-build-multi-lingual.html), which basically generates sub-sites for each languages. I assume you do have variations, for which you need to enable the Variations menu which afterwards is automatically handled by SharePoint, showing the labels for each language (except current one). Have a look at this http://blog.markusb.ch/2012/03/enable-variation-label-menu-in-sharepoint-2010/ and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms562040.aspx

I would strongly suggest you go through the excellent series from Stefan Gossner http://blogs.technet.com/b/stefan_gossner/archive/2011/11/29/sharepoint-variations-the-complete-guide-part-12-customization.aspx

Comment: Actually English and Arabic sites are already there and I can open them if I write their URL in browser like this:    
http://server/sites/mysite/English/Pages/default.aspx    
http://server/sites/mysite/Arabic/Pages/default.aspx    
But I don't want to manually type it and want to have a link  (with my own CSS) on top to change website language.

Comment: Yes, indeed, the variations are already created, irelevant of the menu being enabled. But with the Variations label menu you get exactly what you look for, automatically - links pointing to language sites and automatically hiding language